# What is the difference between BeforeClass and BeforeTest in TestNG - Selenium WebDriver

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, testng

What is the difference between BeforeClass and BeforeTest in TestNG - Selenium WebDriver, please suggest me best link or site for this.

Comment: Maybe answers to the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30587454/difference-between-beforeclass-and-beforetest-in-testng can clarify it to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a duplicate question of below :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30587454/difference-between-beforeclass-and-beforetest-in-testng

since you asked site to refer please consider below websites:

You can refer below link:

https://www.guru99.com/all-about-testng-and-selenium.html

Answer (score 6):

`@BeforeTest` method runs before the test method, belonging to the classes inside the  tag. It is called once for each test tag. It is used to initialize common objects between different test classes inside one test tag.

`@BeforeClass` method runs before the class is invoked. It is called once for each test class inside the test tag. It is used to initialize common objects between different test methods inside one test class.

For example:

```
   <suite name="suit1">
      <test name="TestTag1">
        <classes>
          <class name="TestClass1"/>
        </classes>
      </test>
      <test name="TestTag2">
        <classes>
          <class name="TestClass2"/>
          <class name="TestClass3"/>
        </classes>
      </test>
    </suite>
```

Here, `@BeforeTest` will be called twice, one time before `TestTag1` the second time before `TestTag2` while `@BeforeClass` will be called three times, one time before `TestClass1` the second time before `TestClass2` and the third time before `TestClass3`

[Site for Reference](https://www.edureka.co/community/50124/what-is-the-difference-between-beforeclass-and-beforetest)

Comment: thank you for valuable answer.

Comment: @sushen Do accept the answer which is most applicable to you, by clicking the tick sign near to the answer.